# File Operations on C

Tags: c, file

I wrote dynamic array to file.(100 width)And I read it from file.

But I realised that I can't read all of elements that I malloc from memory.

My code example is below:

```
main()
{
    FILE *file;
     int *numbers;
     int *numbers2;

     numbers = (int *)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
     numbers2 = (int *)malloc(100*sizeof(int)); 


    int i,j,tane;

    file=fopen("numbers.txt","w++");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    { numbers[i]=i;}

    if(file==NULL)
    {printf("Error:File cannot open \n");
     return 1;
    }


    else {
          fwrite(numbers,4,100,file);

         }
    rewind(file);

    printf("Numbers read from file:\n");
    tane=fread(numbers2,4,100,file);
    for(i=0;i<tane;i++)
    { printf("%d ",numbers2[i]);}


    fclose(file);
    getch();
}
```

I see 0-25 elements that is printed by C .
I can't understand that all of the elements doesn't print.( 0 to 100)

Could you help me please?

Best Regards...

Answer (score 2):

You are opening your file in *text* mode, but you are writing *binary* data.  Try `fopen("numbers.txt", "wb+")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `sizeof (int)` in your implementation is not 4.

I'm pretty sure it is `sizeof (int)` though. Try using `sizeof (int)` instead of magic constants. Even better would be to use the object itself as operand to `sizeof` ...

```
fwrite(numbers, sizeof *numbers, 100, file);
/*     also get rid of the MAGIC 100      */
```

Comment: +1 I don't think that's the OP problem, but it's important enough :)

Comment: Yeah ... when I first saw that he only got back 1/4 of the initial array this was my initial thought ... but then I noticed the absence of the `b` and realized Windows interprets `26` as EOF when reading in text mode :/

Answer (score -1):

Fread function returns the numbers of line reads and not number of characters ok? 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/